# Wierd names on WCF's xml schema

Tags: wcf, xsd

I'm stuck with this problem in my WCF services that are being published via IIS.

Since I'm not english native, maybe I lack the right terms to find the right answer.

I have a generic class called Result which encapsulates an operation result code and a type which the methods return, so two of the cases in which I used it are like this:

Result Register 
Result> GetAddressBook

Now, I'd expect to get generated in my types on the xsd respectively a ResultOfCustomerInfo and a ResultOfListOfAddressBookEntry.

When I list my xsd, I have ResultOfCustomerInfoZEwW4PK0 and ResultOfArrayOfAddressBookEntryZEwW4PK0.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this ZEwW4PK0 at the end. Is there a way to force a specific name to be in the xsd generated by WCF?

Could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The solution to my problem came from this blog:
http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx